# Lubuntu 16.04 breaks after installing libgtk-3-dev

Tags: lubuntu, freeze

I have a problem with installation of libgtk-3-dev every time I install it on fresh Lubuntu 16.04 after reboot, system wont load and its stuck at black screen with underscore "_". Someone already had this problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: Probably update all installed packages. Ubuntu **16.04.6** is relatively "fresh" (earlier versions than 'rev.6' are not.) ... When all packages are upgraded to the latest versions, I guess you can install `libgtk-3-dev` with no issues.

Comment: Lubuntu support for 16.04 ended in April. Perhaps it might be wise to upgrade to 18.04 instead?